# iPhone: repeating background task

Tags: iphone, objective-c, background, apple-push-notifications

I am looking for alternatives to push notifications. I would like my app to periodically connect to the server and check for new messages in some kind of background task. If new messages are found I can use Local Notifications to inform the user, but as far as I know Apple doesn't like apps running in the background.

Is there some way to schedule code to run at some set interval, even when the app is in the background, or shutdown completely? (for those of you who know Android, I'm looking for something like BroadcastReciever and Service) If I could do that it would solve all my problems.

TIA!

PS: we are developing for iOS 4+

Comment: What do you mean "pay for Apple's Push Notification service"? There are no fees associated with using it (other than the standard app developer fee).

Comment: I must have read that somewhere, but you're right. I have edited the post to exclude that statement. Thanks!

Comment: hi...i also want to call my web service daily at a particular time(the time set for local notification )...even app is in background...how can i do it..

Comment: @Rajneesh071 This isn't possible on iOS. Apple has specifically blocked that kind of operation. This is very easy to do on Android.

Comment: hmm ... but i want to do this task...can i use push notification...

Comment: @Rajneesh071 A push notification will encourage the user to open the app, but wont guarantee it. Push notifications do not cause code to run.

Comment: in push notification can we send different data daily..without open our app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a good mechanism in iOS to do this unfortunately. Your only two options are to use the location services (significantLocationChange) to get notified in the background when the device moved, or pretend to be a VOIP app in which case you can request processing time at a specified interval. The second method won't get your app approved for the App Store though.